# Workaround for being unable to put code in interfaces

Tags: c#, interface

Let's say I have an interface that many many distinct classes implement:

```
public interface IHaveObjects
{
    object firstObject();
}
```

(Note: I can't make it an abstract base class as implementors of IHaveObjects may already have a base class.)

Now I want to add a new method to the interface, so that one implementer of the interface can have special behaviour for it. Ideally I would do something like this:

```
public interface IHaveObjects
{
    object firstObject();
    object firstObjectOrFallback()
    {
        return firstObject();
    }
}
```

then go to that one implementor of the interface and give it the override:

```
public class ObjectHaverPlus : IHaveObjects
{
    public override object IHaveObjects.firstObjectOrFallback()
    {
        return firstObject() ?? getDefault();
    }
}
```

However it is forbidden in C# to provide a method body in an interface, and I would like to avoid going to every single implementer of `IHaveObjects` to drop in a definition of `firstObjectOrFallback()`. (Imagine if there are hundreds or thousands)

Is there a way to do this without lots of copy paste?

Comment: Why not create a second interface for that special case?  You can't have multiple inheritance of classes, but you can implement multiple interfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about introducing a second interface which inherits from IHaveObjects.

Than you only have to change these classes, which need the new interface with the new method.

This looks like:

```
  interface I1
    {
        void Method1();
    }

    interface I2 : I1
    {
        void Method2();
    }
```

Comment: Oh...I like that...didn't even think about inheritance in my answer.  Silly me :)

Comment: Yes, but this is not possible in c#. I gave him an alternative way.

Comment: @Tomtom I think this is what I want to do. It means doing another check to see if the object is of the extended interface, but that should be fine. Thank you

Comment: that isn't an alternative because his problem isn't the Interface it self it his problem is how an interface works

Comment: @WiiMaxx - When a given path isn't viable/allowed, then an alternative is perfectly acceptable.  At least the OP seems to think so, since this was the accepted answer.  Being a developer is all about being able to solve the problem with the tools at hand.

Comment: @Tim sure, but it wasn't really what he was asking for ... but it doesn't matter aslong he is fine with this answer

Answer (score 2):

That's the problem with interfaces - they don't have any default implementation so any changes to them are breaking changes - i.e. code needs to be modified to work with new version of interface.

Since your implementations already have base classes on their own - you cannot turn it into abstract class, nor does `C#` have multiple class inheritance.

What you can do is to think - is it really a method on interface? Or could it be implemented as an `extension method` on interface (didn't try that but I suppose it will work just fine)?

If it is a method on interface and it should stay there - you may think of breaking this interface into two parts, second inheriting from the first (`IHaveObjectsAndSupportDefault : IHaveObjects`) and use this interface where default value is truly needed (like some other answers indicate).

Answer (score 1):

I may have misunderstood your question, but why not use a second interface, something like:

```
public interface IHaveObjectsEnhanced
{

    object FirstObjectOrFallback();
}
```

Then you could implement the first and second interface:

```
public class ObjectHaverPlus : IHaveObjects, IHaveObjectsEnhanced
{

    public object FirstObject()
    {

    }

    public object FirstObjectOrFallback()
    {
         return FirstObject() ?? GetDefault();
    }

}
```